# How to give two decimal point of double which converted from String value in android java

Tags: java, android, dynamic

I Have String Value.
then how to convert in float value and then give it two decimal points?

Answer (score 0):

Get String value from Source of Value.

Then Convert it in `double`

after declare `DecimalFormat` Method. and follow bellowed step.

```
String value = "10.0000000"
double valueInFloat = Double.parseDouble(value);
```

Declare Method Now.

```
DecimalFormat decimalPoint = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
textview.setText(decimalPoint.formate(valueInFloat));
```

Output: is `10.00`